# Fast moving bright star with eliptic course, instant stop

Tags: star, movement

Around 13 years ago I saw fast moving bright star with eliptic course which crossed half a sky in 1-2 sec and stopped instantly like it was a smashed like a bug, and didn't move for a while few minutes, then I went my way. I saw many falling stars and sattelits mouvements, planes on night, but never something similar.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank for response! But it made almost a full circle across half a sky in 1-2 second smooth one way movement, not zig zig movements. It was as bright as Jupiter when instant stopped. Any scientific explanation? It will puzzle me untill I die. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but after 13 years you can not trust your own memory of what you saw. It's is very likely that *elliptic*, *1-2 sec*, *half the sky* and *few minutes* are off by an order of magnitude. We all think we can remember this exactly, but we can't.